# Are there any public database or map that keeps track of reported bed bug infestation in France?

Tags: france, online-resources, health, paris, bed-bugs

From what I [read](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/bedbug-infestation-paris-london-train-b2423574.html), there is currently a bed bug infestation in Paris, France. Such an infestation often affects places used by travelers such as public transportation, hotels and Airbnb.

Are there any public database or map that keeps track of reported bed bug infestations  in France in accommodations typically used by travelers (eg, hotels, Airbnb) and public transportation?

Comment: Traveling and tourism is one way bedbugs spread (in a suitcase or clothes), so definitely this is travel  oriented.

Comment: @GregHewgill do you plan to look at the questions tagged with [health] and closed a good portion of them because they are public health questions? E.g.,  [Drinking fountain at Lake Garda, Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/183914/1810);  [Is there an international vaccine registry where I can store all my vaccination records in one place?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/182673/1810); [Flights and altitude sickness](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/181489/1810); etc.

Comment: Is there a public database for the US? https://www.orkin.com/press-room/2023-top-bed-bug-cities-list

Comment: What you are expecting is unclear and the way you describe bed bugs infestations seems based on unverified media reports rather than a clear understanding of how they work.

Comment: @Relaxed I wrote an answer to give you an idea. I have had 2 bed bugs infestations in my own place when traveling so far (both in the US), so I have [some knowledge of it](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/479/31).

Comment: @Relaxed It a bit more than 'unverified media reports': [2023-10-04: BBC News: Bedbug panic sweeps Paris as infestations soar before 2024 Olympics](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-66995977): "Every late summer we see a big increase in bedbugs," says Jean-Michel Berenger, an entomologist at Marseille's main hospital and France's leading expert on les punaises. "That is because people have been moving about over July and August, and they bring them back in their luggage. And each year, the seasonal increase is bigger than the last one."

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not really, you need to separate the growing prevalence of bedbugs, which has been [observed in many places for years](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/170502/Cimikose-Bettwanzen-Weltweit-auf-dem-Vormarsch) and the recent panic behind this question. In particular, the notion that this “typically affects […] public transportation” is based on unverified reports.

Comment: Suddenly every media outlet has to cover it and hastily pieces together some anecdotes about cinemas or trains, giving the impression of a sudden infestation centred on Paris. But that's not what's going on. In fact, that's exactly what the BBC article is trying to debunk: “In part it is true. But in another part it isn't. […] The fact of the matter is that bedbugs are making a comeback, and have been for perhaps 20 or 30 years. But that is not just in France, but everywhere.”

Comment: @Relaxed hence the usefulness of this question to quantify the actual situation. I’d be happy to ask for any countries, but I’d expect it would be closed as too broad.

Comment: As I explained, the question was too confused to be useful.

Comment: @Relaxed you didn’t explain how “Are there any public database or map that keeps track of reported bed bug infestations in France?” confused you.

Comment: @Relaxed It is simply another form of [Invasive species - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasive_species) that must be delt with before it establishes itsself. Making people aware (in a responsible manor) of the problem is the first step.

Comment: I agree with the question being relevant to people traveling as it is written now and voted to reopen.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not that this has much to do with my comments but it's not an invasive species, it's a parasite that cannot live without humans. It's not coming from anywhere or spreading in the environment. It's fully established in Europe (or indeed everywhere where humans live) and won't be eradicated. Awareness is fine, the first step is understanding instead of spreading completely misleading models of what bed bugs are.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I did, it was unclear whether you're hoping for a list of addresses, cities or what. In fact, your edit shows you understood exactly what the problem was. It clarifies the question but it doesn't match the answer you posted and is not really a reasonably way to deal with the problem. And it doesn't address the confusion in your first sentence either. The reality is that bed bugs increasingly are and will remain present. It makes no sense to speak of “a bed bug infestation” at the scale of a city.

Answer (score 1):

I found a report [Consultations liées aux punaises de lit
en médecine générale en France métropolitaine, période 2019‐2020](https://www.sentiweb.fr/document/5008) that contains some statistics on bed bug infestations in France:

[image]